# How to put my C# code in string to pass to an e-mail?

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-core-mvc, quartz.net

I am using Mailkit to send an email.

So in the body of the email, I am passing data like this:

```
message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
    foreach (var item in model.Transaction)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Account +"-"+item.Amount+"-"+item.Date);
    }

    Text = @"";
};
```

but I wanted to put `item.Account`, `item.Amount`, `item.Date` in @""

How can I do that?

Comment: Probably you wanted to do something like `Text = $"{item.Account}-{item.Amount}-{item.Date}";`?

Comment: You could `Text = string.Join("\r\n", model.Transaction.Select(item => $"<--as above-->"));`

Answer (score 1):

you should use `$`

```
$"{item.Account}, {item.Amount}, {item.Date}";
```

Because `@` is used to escaping specials symbols

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access `item.*` outside of `foreach`*.

To create a single string from multiple strings you could use `string.Join`:

```
List<string> l = new ();
foreach (var item in model.Transaction)
{
   var fromSingleItem = $"{item.Account}-{item.Amount}-{item.Date}";
   l.Append(fromSingleItem);
}
var fromAllItems = string.Join(", ", l);
```

* = What would time outside of `foreach` mean? Would it be the first item's data, or the last one's, or from the middle?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a string builder for this

```
 var sb= new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in model.Transaction)
{
sb.Append( item.Account + "-" + item.Amount.ToString() + "-" 
+ item.Date.ToString() + "\n");
}

message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
     Text = sb.ToString();
};
```

or if you have only several items

```
var sb= string.Empty;

foreach (var item in model.Transaction)
{
sb+= item.Account + "-" + item.Amount.ToString() + "-" + item.Date.ToString() + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Serge has the right idea, but I would tweak it a bit as there is a performance penalty every time you concatenate using the '+' symbol (a new String object is instantiated when you concatenate with '+'). I would suggest you continue to use StringBuilder even if you only have a single item in your foreach loop.

```cs
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in model.Transaction)
{
    builder.Append(item.Account);
    builder.Append("-");
    builder.Append(item.Amount);
    builder.Append("-");
    builder.AppendLine(item.Date);
}

message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
    Text = builder.ToString()
};
```